# Logging adjacency list to text file/remote ip in ovs switch

Tags: python, controller, mininet, openflow

Is there a way of logging adjacency information to text file/remote controller in  non-SDN ovs switch (that is incompatible with OpenFlow `failMode='standalone'`)?

I have created switches as

```
s1 = net.addSwitch('s1', cls=OVSSwitch13, failMode='standalone', stp=1)
```

I need the topology of all switches (SDN/ non SDN) in the controller.

UPDATE: I do know that stp vlog can be enabled (http://ask.xmodulo.com/enable-logging-open-vswitch.html). But then I need to send it to controller and also parse it. How to do that?